# PHP/SQL duoble drop down from SQL table

Tags: php, select

I have a nested drop down choice where, basically, the second select input should update its content depending on first selected option.
I get it working ok when it open the page but did not exactly understood how to update the variable once the page is loaded. As a matter of fact if the last option of the SQL table in the first option match the name of one or more record in the second input those may correctly be selected but - changing the option - the second input box doesn’t update. 
I tried some java but hadn’t succeeded, also thought about AJAX. Can any one help me with that?

My code is following, the $namev variable is the one, I guess, should need some correct action to be handled toward second input box:

```
<head>
```

…..

```
    </head>


<body>
```

…..

```
        <form>
```

…….

```
            <div class="divFLOATleft">
                <label>voce</label>
                    <?php

                        $result = $conn->query("select id_voce,id_gruppo_voce,gruppo_voce,voce FROM voci");
                        echo "<select name='voce'><option value='' disabled selected>scegli voce</option>";

                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                                                unset($idv, $namev);
                                                                $idv = $row['id_voce'];
                                                                $namev = $row['voce']; 
                                                                $id_gv = $row['id_gruppo_voce'];
                                                                $id_v = $row['gruppo_voce'];                                                                    
                                                                echo '<option value="'.$idv.'">'.$namev.'</option>';

                                                            }
                            echo "</select>";



                            echo"</div>";

                            echo"<div class='divFLOATleft'>";
                            echo"<label>categoria</label>";


                        $result = $conn->query("select id_voce,id_gruppo_voce,gruppo_voce,voce FROM voci WHERE gruppo_voce LIKE '$namev'");
                        echo "<select name='voce'><option value='' disabled selected>scegli categoria</option>";

                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                                                unset($id, $name);
                                                                $idc = $row['id_voce'];
                                                                $namec = $row['voce']; 
                                                                $id_gc = $row['id_gruppo_voce'];
                                                                $id_c = $row['gruppo_voce'];
                                                                echo '<option value="'.$idc.'">'.$namec.'</option>';

                                                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                    ?>

            </div>                  


        </form>
```

…..

```
</body>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX read this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: @ArleighHix - I give it a look, maybee also yesterday but up to now using their example still have the problem that it positivelu rewrite the paragrpah but miss to retrieve the data from the SQL table.... of course it has to be a problem related to my transcription and anyway in my case the query is ok, but still did not really get how to mix this example in my code.... I'll keep on try ;)

Comment: definitevely did it expecially thanks to https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp but had to split the code and use a call to an external as in that example - does any one know how to hide the second dropdown item if no match are returned from SQL query?

Comment: You could build the second select html based on the query result and then return the entire select, and replace the existing element with that. So if you have no matches just return `<select name='voce' hidden><option value='' selected></option></select>`